# Travis persists on `Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, travis-ci

I am trying to set up a Travis configuration for my RoR app, but I cannot get passed from the the access point for the MySQL database. here is my `.travis` contents:

```
language: ruby

rvm:
  - 2.4.0

cache: bundler

sudo: required

env:
  - RAILS_ENV=test

matrix:
  fast_finish: true

services:
  - mysql

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - imagemagick libmagickwand-dev

before_install:
  - bash .travis.install-mysql-5.7
  - gem update --system 2.6.11
  - gem update bundler

before_script:
  - cp .travis.database.yml config/database.yml

script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

And in my `.travis.database.yml` I've have done everything by [the book](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/):

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  username: root

development:
  <<: *default
  database: site_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: site_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: site_production
  username: site
  password: <%= ENV['SITE_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Here is the Travis' output:

```
$ cp .travis.database.yml config/database.yml

$ RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create
#<Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'>
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "username"=>"root", "database"=>"site_test"}, {:charset=>"utf8"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
Created database 'site_test'

The command "RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create" exited with 0.
$ RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

#### Question:

1. What the bloody is wrong with travis or my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it worth, I forgot to reset the newly installed MySQL 5.7's username & password, noticed from [here](https://medium.com/@mtparet/install-mysql-server-5-7-on-travis-96f2ebc0f339#.bsjosi8z2).

Answer (score 0):

What's root's password for mysql?

Add that to

```
test:
  <<: *default
  database: site_test
  password: ROOT_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE
```

Comment: It is blank! but not for the newly installed MySQL 5.7.